# Does the function $\overbrace{\int dx \int dx \cdots \int dx \int \frac{1}{1-e^x}dx}^{\mbox{$n$ times}}$ (integrating $n$ times) have a closed form?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The function $$f(x,n)=\overbrace{\int dx \int dx \cdots \int dx \int \frac{1}{1-e^x}dx}^{\mbox{$n$ times}} $$ where $n$ is the integrating times.
Does the function have a closed form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x>0$
$$I_n(x)=\int dx \int dx \cdots \int dx \int \frac{1}{1-e^x}dx$$
$$\implies I_n(x)=\int dx \int dx \cdots \int dx \int -e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-kx} dx$$
$$\implies I_n(x)=\int dx \int dx \cdots \int dx \int - \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} e^{-px} dx$$
$$\implies I_n(x)=\int dx \int dx \cdots \int   \left(\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-px}}{p}+C_1\right)dx$$
Successively,
$$I_n=(-1)^{n+1} \sum_{k-1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-px}}{p^n}+P_{n-1}(x)$$
$$\implies I_n(x)=(-1)^{n+1} \text{Li}_n(e^{-x})+P_{n-1}(x).$$
Here $\text{Li}_n(z)$ well known polylog functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

and $P_{n-1}(x)$ are the polynomials of irder $n-1$ with undetermined co-efficients. For $n=1$, we have
$I_1(x)=\ln(1-e^{-x})+C_1.$

Edit:  Similarly one can write $I_n(x)$ for $x<.0.$

Comment: Excellent, But I hope we can have other closed form than this kind.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a closed form which only contains a finite number of elementary functions as you wish.

Comment: @Z Ahmed, you got the closed form on the interval $]0,+\infty[$. Please, could you also write the closed form on the interval $]-\infty,0[$ ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out,  for negative $X$ we will expand $1/(1-e^x)$ as IGP and work similarly.

Comment: @Angelo just another form, not necessarily containing  a finite number of elementary functions

Comment: In this case, you can use the following series of elementary functions: $$\;Li_n\left(e^{-x}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-kx}}{k^n}\;.$$Hence , $$I_n(x)=(-1)^{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-kx}}{k^n} +P_{n-1}(x)\;.$$ But, @ZAhmed had already written it in his answer. So, why are you asking for another form if you are willing to accept series of elementary functions ?

Comment: Thanks Angelo, your work helps.